# How to change the default outlook file storage path

Tags: path, filepath, outlook-2007

I need to change my default storage path if my outlook. I searched in net but i can't get any clear ideas. can you please any one tell the procedures.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Question of this sort should belong to [superuser.com](http://superuser.com), but however, here is simple way you can achieve it:

1. Quit outlook f it's running.
2. Copy ost/pst data files from current location to you new location.
3. Start outlook , go to File -> data file management.
4. Remove all files except that is default.
5. Add all files from new location.
6. Set new default file.
7. Exit outlook.
8. Start outlook, FIle -> data file management. Remove old default
   file.
9. You are gone.

You can also use Control panel's "mail" applet to achieve this more easy.

Answer (score 0):

3 ways

1. [microsoft support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2752583)
   [microsoft support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2752583)
2. [ms blogs technet](http://blogs.technet.com/b/danstolts/archive/2012/11/07/how_2d00_to_2d00_change_2d00_default_2d00_data_2d00_file_2d00_ost_2d00_location_2d00_in_2d00_office_2d00_2013.aspx)
3. [move outlook folder](http://blogs.technet.com/b/danstolts/archive/2012/11/07/how_2d00_to_2d00_change_2d00_default_2d00_data_2d00_file_2d00_ost_2d00_location_2d00_in_2d00_office_2d00_2013.aspx)

```
   -with outlook close, move the default %userprofile%\appdata\local\microsoft\outlook to desired folder
   - using %userprofile%\appdata\local\microsoft as current directory, 
 mklink /d  outlook
  that is all
```